# Modify global with an interface that may or may not be there

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browser, typescript-typings

I'm sharing some code between the browser and node and I'd like to use `performance.now()` instead of `Date.now()` if available. Unfortunately, in node, `performance` is not available and typescript gives me an error. I could add the entire `dom` library, but that pulls in everything, which I'd like to avoid because it would certainly eventually mask real errors. So, how can I modify the global namespace to say: "hey, there's this name `performance` that may or may not exist"

For what it's worth, this is the line that I'm trying to get to compile cleanly in node and the browser:

```
const lastUpdate = typeof performance !== undefined ? performance.now() : Date.now();
```

and this is the error I get:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'performance'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by `typeof` is a string `'undefined'`, NOT a value of `undefined`. So your comparison should be:

```
const lastUpdate = typeof performance !== 'undefined' ? performance.now() : Date.now();
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

Comment: Thank you! Apparently, I'm too dumb for typescript error messages, haha.

Comment: @btmorex nah it got me confused too. But then I realized that the part throwing error was `performance.now()`, not `typeof performance` because the condition was evaluating to true.